# Gap between top of UIScrollView and adjoining view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm trying to figure out why there's a gap between my scroll view (topped by the pink) and the upper view (black).

[image: gap between scroll view and top view]

I have created this in interface builder. The pink view is inside a UIScrollView that is set to have its top == bottom of the black view above it:

[image: layout constraints]

Why is there this gap and how can I stop it?

Here is a slice of the entire screen to give you an idea:

[image]

I am having the same difficulty both at the top and bottom of the scroll view. There is a white gap between the top view of the scroll view and the next view up, and similarly there is a gap at the bottom view for the scroll view and the bottom of the screen. I tried turning off 'bounces enabled' but that has not fixed the problem. What gives?

Comment: Please add a full image of your interface builder. It's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: Could you give me more information? Anyway maybe it's considering the status bar. Try `Top Space to: Superview`.

Comment: try this in viewdidload self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=false